# AWS SDK: cannot import AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder to get temp credentials

Tags: scala, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java

There are a couple of examples on the AWS SDK how to get the credentials, e.g.:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-sts.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html

But when I run these snippets I cannot import `AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder`:

```scala
// note that the AWS SDK is pretty brittle across versions.
import $ivy.`com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4`
import $ivy.`org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3`

import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder

var clientRegion = "*** Client region ***";
var roleARN = "*** ARN for role to be assumed ***";
var roleSessionName = "*** Role session name ***";

var stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
    .withRegion(clientRegion)
    .build()
var roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
    .withRoleArn(roleARN)
    .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName)
var roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest)
var sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials()
```

> 

```
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder
       ^cmd16.sc:13: not found: value AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder
var stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                ^Compilation Failed
Compilation Failed
```

- scala version 2.11.12
- spark version 2.3.4, that means that I am tight to hadoop-aws 2.7.3, which depends on aws-java-sdk 1.7.4 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS, this class is not part of the AWS Java SDK until version 1.11.0.

You have to instantiate the `AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient` class yourself instead, without using the builder.

Call this [constructor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.html#AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient-com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials-):

```
val stsClient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
stsClient.setRegion(clientRegion)
```

Comment: ok... can you give an example or send a resource on how to proceed?

Comment: ProfileCredentialsProvider is private. can't do this